# Custom selectableItemBackground

Tags: android, android-styles, android-recyclerview

I'm using a RecyclerView for a list. I've a found a really nice solution to give the list click feedback and ripple (on Lollipop).
Basically I'm giving my row layout the attribute:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

And everything is fine, except that I need a different background color for my list (default state). How can I override just the basic state background (not clicked) giving it a different color?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415056/using-a-custom-color-for-button-background-while-using-selectableitembackground.  Alternatively, what happens if you use: `foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` instead?  Then you can set your color with `background`.

Answer (score 8):

This will give custom background color and default grey ripple effect:

```
android:background="@color/YourCustomColor"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: it helped me a lot, this way we can use the background we want and keep the great click feedback.
[Wrap your row view inside a frame layout.](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/material-part-5/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `CardViews` in your `RecyclerView`? If so, programmatically use `.setCardBackgroundColor()` in your `holder` to each `CardView`. Alternatively, you can wrap everything in a simple dummy `FrameLayout` (with an android:id) in the `CardView`, and programmatically change that layout's background when you bind the `ViewHolders`.